# Last part of a url (after the "/")

Tags: string-manipulation, webservices, url

I want the last number after the "/". How can I do that?

```
"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208009v1"
```

I just want **0208009v1**

I want to import multiple links from the following:

```
{{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208009v1"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0227v1"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5143v2"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509348v1"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608711v2"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002018v2"}}
```

I just want the last number in the following links. How would that work?

Comment: Is there any reason why `Last[StringSplit["http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208009v1", "/"]]` doesn't suit your needs?

Comment: I want to do it for multiple links. For example: 

{{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208009v1"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0227v1"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5143v2"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509348v1"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608711v2"}, \
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002018v2"}}

How can I only get the last number for this?

Comment: Perhaps use `Map[]` along with the method in my previous comment? In any event, you should be editing your question to mention that multiple links are expected.

Comment: Last[StringSplit[#], "/"] & /@ Values[a], this isn't working I tried it

Comment: I don't have Mathematica running just now to check this out, but you might try [this example from the documentation](https://wolfram.com/xid/0mlic35bi3tm-vb9yu):  `Last[URLParse[urlstring,"Path"]]`

Comment: What you tried didn't work because a. you forgot to `Flatten[]` your list, and b. `Values[]` is not intended for nested lists like what you have, so it's not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 4):

In addition, using a modification of this [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8798197/499167):

```
(StringCases[#, RegularExpression["[^/]+$"]]&/@list)//Flatten
```

> {0208009v1, 0905.0227v1, 0907.5143v2, 0509348v1, 0608711v2, 0002018v2}

where

```
list = {{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208009v1"}, 
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0227v1"}, 
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5143v2"},
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509348v1"}, 
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608711v2"}, 
{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002018v2"}};
```

Comment: Maybe `(StringCases[#, RegularExpression["([^/]+)/?$"]:> "$1"]&/@list)//Flatten` if there is an unwanted trailing slash (eg "http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002018v2/")

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208009v1"}, 
 {"http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.0227v1"}, 
 {"http://arxiv.org/abs/0907.5143v2"},
 {"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0509348v1"}, 
 {"http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0608711v2"}, 
 {"http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0002018v2"}};
```

In addition to [`StringSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringSplit.html) suggested by J.M. in comments,

```
StringSplit[Flatten@list, "/"][[All, -1]]
```

you can  also use

#### [`StringTrim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTrim.html)

```
StringTrim[Flatten[list], StartOfString ~~ ___ ~~ "/"]
```

#### [`StringReplace`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringReplace.html)

```
StringReplace[Flatten[list], StartOfString ~~ ___ ~~ "/" -> ""]
```

#### [`StringCases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringCases.html)

```
Flatten @ StringCases[Flatten@list, "/" ~~ a : Except["/"] .. ~~ EndOfString :> a]
```

#### [`StringDrop`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringDrop.html) + [`StringPosition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringPosition.html):

```
MapThread[StringDrop, {Flatten@list, Max /@ StringPosition[Flatten@list, "/"]}]
```

#### [`FileNameSplit`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameSplit.html)

```
Last /@ FileNameSplit /@ Flatten[list]
```

to get

> ```
> {"0208009v1", "0905.0227v1", "0907.5143v2", "0509348v1", "0608711v2",    "0002018v2"}
> ```

Comment: Consider also `Last[URLParse[#, "Path"]] & /@ Flatten[list]`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the simplest solution is just `StringExtract[Flatten[list], "/" -> -1]`.